git submodule missing branches if setup through git submodule init + update
I have a git repository with a submodule. I need to change the branch the submodule is pointing to after the repo has been cloned and set up (for context, this is in a gitlab CI job).
In a terminal, if I clone the repo with git clone --recurse-submodules, then everything is fine and I can switch the submodule's branch using
git submodule set-branch ...
git submodule update --remote

with no problem. Going into the submodule subdir and running git branch -a -v, I see that all the submodule's branches are there.
But if I clone the repo without --recurse-submodules, and then set the submodule up with
git submodule init
git submodule update

and then try to set the submodule branch with set-branch ... update --remote as above, I generally get an error Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/<branch> revision in submodule path <submodule>. If I cd into the submodule and run git branch -a -v, I see that only a few of the existing branches are there.
So my question is, how do I get all the missing submodule branches, or at least the one I need ?
I tried various options of git fetch (--unshallow, --deepen, --all) but nothing works.
Any way to do this ?
Alternatively, I can't find a way to force gitlab to use --recurse-submodules, the various GIT_SUBMODULE_* variables don't seem to make much of a difference.
Thanks for any help
[EDIT]
After many tries and tips from a colleague, this is what seems to work :
On my macbook, it's relatively simple :
git rm <submodule>
git submodule add -b <the_branch_i_need> <submodule_repo_url>

On GitLab CI, for some reason it ended up being much more complicated :
cd <submodule>
git reset --hard
cd ..
git rm -f <submodule>
git submodule add -f -b <the_branch_i_need> --name foobar <submodule_repo_url>

Somehow there are changes pending in the submodule, and I had to specify a different name for the submodule, otherwise it would complain that the submodule was already existing.

"Somehow there are changes pending in the submodule, and I had to specify a different name for the submodule, otherwise it would complain that the submodule was already existing." Because git rm -f <submodule> is not enough. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/7976758 You need rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule> Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+remove

The stackoverflow post you're quoting is based on a wiki page last edited in 2012. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/1081361 : «In modern git (I'm writing this in 2022, with an updated git installation), this has become quite a bit simpler:
Run git rm , and commit.
This removes the filetree at , and the submodule's entry in the .gitmodules file. I.e. all traces of the submodule in your repository proper are removed.»

git rm <path-to-submodule> is not enough. At least rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule_name> is required.

The page I quoted and my tests on my own machine suggest otherwise. It's only in the gitlab CI environment that I had to jump through more hoops.
